# java error (Class not found)

Tags: java, exception

My code is:

```
    String baglantiURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test";
    String surucu="org.postgresql.Driver";
    try{

        Class.forName(surucu);
        Connection baglanti=DriverManager.getConnection(baglantiURL);
        Statement ifade=baglanti.createStatement();
        String sorgu="select * from tablo";
        ResultSet sonucKumesi=ifade.executeQuery(sorgu);
        while (sonucKumesi.next()) {System.out.println(sonucKumesi.getString(1));


        System.out.println(sonucKumesi.getString(2));
        System.out.println(sonucKumesi.getString(3));

        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class not found");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL error");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println("hata");
    }
}
```

Output is:

> SQL error

What is the wrong?

Comment: You should print out the stack trace for the exceptions, it'll provide you with more useful/helpful information than "SQL error".

Comment: It's hard to take a question seriously when there are careless typos in the code. *grump*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your problem is in the following snippet:

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Class not found");
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("SQL error");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("hata");
}
```

Your code is throwing away most of the information that is going to tell you what the application's problem is.  After each of the `println` calls, add a line to print out the stack trace; e.g.

```
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
```